# GDB on Mac OS Sierra, trying to uninstall and remove all files completely but can't

Tags: c, xcode, gdb, macos-sierra

I should preface this by stating I'm working with Xcode on macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

I installed GDB with `homebrew` and it appeared to install fine until I tried to use it.  In terminal it kept saying that it was not a valid command.  (I'm new to C and was working with my professor.  Even he was baffled when I tried to use it after downloading it in front of him).  So later I tried to install it by creating the make file and still having problems.  I then used `homebrew` again but to uninstall and reinstall, still having problems.

Now I'm at the point where I can't even run my C files when I use `gcc` to compile them.  I simply get a statement that `unable to open file`.  I've read someone suggest to `sudo mv /usr/local /usr/_local` and I'm notified that I don't have permission, even after entering in my password.

I've gotten every error when I try to remove all items belonging to `gdb`.  I've gone as far as removing Xcode in hopes that I can do a fresh install of it all.

I'm at the point where I've begun looking into removing my macports entirely.

I'm looking for any advice into how I can try to start off from a clean slate.  I need to use `gdb` on a project that is due and can't get this up and running.  Please help talk me from a ledge!

**EDIT:**

I have used Sublime to create a simple `Hello World` file and it compiles and runs fine with `gcc`.  So my project file has become corrupted somehow.  At least I can calm down a bit.  But I would still like to get this `gdb` issue figured out and install a fresh copy with everything old removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm working with Xcode on macOS Sierra 10.12.6
>
> I need to use gdb on a project that is due and can't get this up and running

I don't know how to reinstall gdb on macOS, but be aware that gdb is broken on macOS Sierra as of now (at least debugging dynamic libraries), see [Bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20981).

So if you even get gdb correctly installed you can probably end up with nothing (gdb won't be able to debug what you want).

Comment: Yeah I've been reading a lot of similar posts on StackExchange as well as other sources.  I've seen mention of LLDB but haven't tried it.  Website is helpful and LLDB has a section on their site that maps their commands with the GDB commands for easy reference.  I'll have to give that a shot.

Comment: Just a follow up I like it already when working along with Xcode.  Since it is already integrated with Xcode, I simply need to call `LLDB <filename>`.  No need to install anything.  Thanks again for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your file executable using `gcc -Wall -g $fileName.c -o $fileName`. This will show all the errors that might exists. Secondly, if it doesn't work and you absolutely need to use `gdb`, using a VM of Linux(recommend Ubuntu if you're new to Linux or Mate) is a good alternative. You then have to just use `sudo apt-get install gdb` and even install `gdb-dashboard` [git-hub gdb-dashboard](https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard) if you want to do some serious debugging. That's the quickest fix that I can think of you are in a hurry. Btw good VMs are VirtualBox and Parallel Desktop(if you want to have access to your local files from the VM).